# Как выделить дин. память для char[]?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char

Собсна, насколько я понял, я не могу изменять строку, если я инициализировал на неё указатель, примером, `char* a("dududu");` (вызывается исключение с ошибкой доступа при записи, к примеру, `*p = 'a';`). Но я могу создать массив символов: `char a[]("dududu")`, но я не понимаю как внести её в динамическую память через new. Редактор пишет:

> Для агрегатного объекта требуется инициализация с использованием "{...}"

Что это значит (как поправить) или как иначе я могу изменять строку?

Код, приводящий к исключению:

```
char* a("dududu");
char* p(a);
*p = 'a';
```

Comment: А вы не ленитесь скопировать в вопрос код(участок кода).  Ведь многим  может быть не понятен ваш рассказ без кода, Лично я ни .... не понел...

Comment: Мне интереснее узнать, что было непонятно. Но я обновил вопрос

Comment: Я  написал не то, что хотел, поэтому удалил.

Comment: Ваша первая строка создает  массив типа  const char*  и его адрес записывается в указатель.   Ваш указатель только для чтения

Comment: Код `char* a("dududu");` является невалидным, так как в С++ запрещно неявное приведение массива `char const` к указателю на `char`, это у вас видимо расширение gcc.

Comment: Отнюдь, писал на VS2015

Comment: `copystr.cpp:3:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 {char* a("dududu");`

Comment: Используйте `std::string`

Comment: @älёxölüt Класс, спасибо. Мне это не нужно

Comment: @xt1zer почему?

Comment: @älёxölüt Потому

Answer (score 2):

Можно в стеке сделать копию строки так:

```
char str[] = "abcd" ;
str[1]= 'x' ;
```

или в куче так :

```
# include <string.h>
char const * s = "abcd" ;
int l = strlen(s) ;
char * str = new char [l+1];
memcpy(str,s,l+1);
str[1]= 'x' ;
```